# Is there a workaround for something like "Form1.MousePreview:=true"?

Tags: delphi, mouseevent, vcl, mousemove

I have two 100% overlapping panels with different contents on a form.
The first (static display of information) should be visible by default, but the other (user interaction) should replace it if the user moves the mouse near the two - and if the mouse moves away, it should switch back.
Something like this:

```
if (*the mouse is near*) then
begin
  Panel1.Hide;
  Panel2.Show;
end
else
begin
  Panel2.Hide;
  Panel1.Show;
end;
```

My problem is: where to capture mouse movement?
Each component has its own `OnMouseMove` handler - of course I could forward each of them to the forms handler, but I'd rather have something a bit more elegant (and easier to maintain).
The perfect solution would be something like `Form1.MousePreview := true;`.

Another solution would be assigning a generic handler that translates coordinates and calls the forms handler; The assigning could be done in FormCreate.
But that's not as easy as it seems, because one TImage already has its own mouse event handlers.

I have tried `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave` of the two panels but it didn't work; #1 disappeared, but #2 did not appear. I guess that's because if the mouse leaves Panel2, it should disappear - but it also leaves it if it enters a button on it.
That's why I'd like to use a coordinate based approach to make the check more reliable.

Maybe the two panel method is completely wrong?

**Update**: Yes, it is, as Remy said.
I am now using a TJVPageList because a TPageControl has visual tabs.
The `OnMouseEnter` handler of the PageList sets one page, the `OnMouseLeave` sets the other; But once the mouse moves over the PageList, both pages start flickering.
I have tried adding the event handlers to each page, too, but that made no difference.
Should I check *all* `OnMouseEnter` / `Leave` events to filter out the PageList, the two pages and all components sitting on the pages?

**Another update:** I am using a TPageControl now, but the behaviour is similar.
It doesn't flicker, but if I move the mouse ontop the TPageControl, no TTabSheet is displayed at all.
Only if I press down the left mousebutton, the UI sheet is displayed. The other sheet is displayed normally if I move away the mouse. (The TJVPageList displays the UI page if I press the left mousebutton, too.)
I have used the mouse event handlers (enter/leave) of the TPageControl and both TTabSheets.

**Update 3:**
Done it.
The static Panel / TabSheet / JvStandardPage (#1) must not trigger the `OnMouseLeave` handler.

Comment: You can turn off the tabs of a `TPageControl` by setting the `TabVisible` property of each `TTabSheet` to false.

Comment: Thank you very much - I was searching for that property on the TPageControl itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe might be better served using a single `TPageControl` instead of two `TPanel` controls.  Use the `TPageControl`'s own `OnMouseEnter/Leave` events (or intercept the `CM_MOUSEENTER/LEAVE` messages) to switch the `TPageControl.ActivePage` as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that's much better than two panels. But it still doesn't work as wanted - see the edited answer